# AutoLayout of Custom Accordion/Collapsible UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, autolayout, interface-builder

I would like to build a TableView where when the user clicks on a cell it expands to show more information. My question is how do I use Autolayout to arrange the multiple items in each cell.

Each cell will always be the same size, whether it is collapsed or not, so the sizing isn't dynamic.

The first problem I have is how to use Autolayout to arrange all the items in the cell. Before Xcode 7 I was successfully using Autolayout where I would pick a label-button-view to arrange, click **Editor > Align > Trailing/Leading/Top Space,  to**.. etc. This is now greyed out and I don't know how to replace my old strategy.

Each cell has two rows of items. The first row shows all the time, the second only shows on collapse. Below is a picture of how the cell will look when it is collapsed:

[image]

The first row is a bit trickier because outlet1 and outlet 2 will have variable sizes. I would like 'label' to come right after label1, no matter how long or short that outlet happens to be. As arranged currently, there is a variable amount of space between the two.

What I'm looking to achieve in row 1 is basically exactly like Venmo:

[image]

Notice how **'paid'** conforms to the size of the two names in the first row.

The second row has two buttons and an outlet which will always be the same size.

To sum up - how can I layout these elements in the UITableView for iphones4 thru 6S - and then how do I make this cell a collapsible cell? The construction of these cells seem to work as a system, not isolated from the whole - which is why this is a 2-part question.

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want to achieve?

[image]

Comment: Yes it's similar to what you showed however I would like that cells only to show "Ky Nguyen answered SamYou...   Time + Image"... if a user clicked on that one cell then it would open up and show the Like and Comment button